# eslint disallow file names ending with pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, lint

How can I disallow particular file names with eslint?

For example if someone calls a file `MyClassStyle`, eslint would fail because the file ends with `Style`. In other words - no file should end with `Style`.

I looked at eslint-plugin-filenames but I don't think it is possible to do it with that.

Comment: Probably you should have that as a rule in your editor to don't allow you to create files with that name in the first place.

Comment: This is for all devs in the project. It should be sorted by linter.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-filenames - maybe this can help you

Comment: well.. thanks, but I have that literally in the question content..